# Difference between src/main/java and src/test/java in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven

While creating a new Maven project, the directories `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` are created. With some googling, I came to know that my `main` source code that I use for testing must be placed in `src/main/java`. But then, what is the purpose of two separate directories. The current answer on a similar question didn't help much.

Comment: The code under `src/test` is not included in the production build.

Comment: What do you mean by "main source code that I use for testing"?

Comment: `main` is for production, `test` is only for testing before putting into production.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maven and other build management environments (e.g. gradle) are based on the assumption that you do automated testing via e.g. unit tests. For that you need extra code for testing that should not be included in your final product delivered to your customer.

Thus, everything that goes into `src/main/java` is per default packaged into the product that you would deliver for your customer whereas everything that you put into `src/test/java` is not.

This is an advantage for various reasons:

- your delivered products are smaller
- it is easier to to find testrelated code inside your project
- you can load various libraries only for testing.
- ...

Comment: Also note that tests are run as part of the normal Maven build, therefore they need to be fast ("unit tests") and not depend on infrastructure.  My personal conclusion is that integration tests etc should go in another project.  I believe this to be a design shortcoming in Maven.

Answer (score 3):

As per the Maven configurations, tests class will be found in the `src/test` directory and the source code will be found in the `src/main` directory. So `src/main/java` is the root directory for your source code & `src/test/java/` is the root directory for your `test` code.

Ex: Hotel Package, Reservation class

```
Source Class file :  src/main/java/Hotel/Reservation.java
Test Class file : src/test/java/Hotel/ReservationTest.java
```

Answer (score 2):

`src/main/java` places your code that use for real production.
`src/test/java` places your test use case code, like junit test. These codes would be executed when doing maven package things. These codes won't be packaged to your war or jar file. Which means these codes won't for real production.

Plus: Unit test codes are not required to be packaged in production. You don't need to and should not to put them in `src/main/java` folder.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to have test code and production code (`src/main/java`) separate is, that it is easier to build the application by just including production code.

Answer (score 0):

To make types easier to find and use, to avoid naming conflicts, and to control access, programmers bundle groups of related types into packages.[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)